# MinGW fails on Windows XP

Tags: c++, qt, windows-xp, mingw, msvcrt

I'm using the MinGW-builds toolchain provided by Qt 5.0.2 to build a project. Overall, things are going well, but I seem to have run into a snag. When a beta tester ran the program on his Windows XP machine, the program instantly crashes with the following error:

[image: XP crash dialog]

I poked around using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and discovered two things:

1. msvcrt.dll gets involved when MinGW's C++ runtime links to it:
   [image: Link trail]
2. amazingly, his computer (and several other computers in the office) have versions of msvcrt.dll (the Windows C runtime library) so old that they lack all the ["secure" CRT additions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh(v=vs.80).aspx) (which MinGW's C++ runtime apparently uses).

Installing the Visual C++ runtime Qt provides (in `Qt\Qt5.0.2\vcredist`) does nothing to solve the problem, as more recent versions of the runtime such as the one Qt uses provides different files (such as VS11's msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll) instead of replacing the old one.

Is there any workaround? It would seem that all versions of MinGW link to this file, and I would really prefer not to switch over to Visual Studio 2010 (the other option Qt 5 offers) due to its poor C++11 support. An initial idea would be to have the installer replace the old msvcrt.dll with a newer one, but

1. Many programs are actively using the runtime (imagine that), so it can't just be overwritten.
2. It sounds extremely evil for an installer for a piddly userspace application to reach into `C:\Windows\System32` and start replacing files.

Comment: To my knowledge you are not forced by to use the secure version of the crt api in mingw. Now just to make sure I understand, is it your code that uses functions like memmove_s or is it the QT library doing this? If yes, have you compiled QT yourself or is it a binary distribution you're using?

Comment: I'm using the QT binary distribution, but neither my code nor QT (as far as I know) are using it. It's MinGW's runtime (libstdc++) that's using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy of `libstdc++-6.dll` that is installed with the prebuilt Qt 5.0.2 (with MinGW) package (`qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe`) doesn't import `memmove_s` from `msvcrt.dll`.

Here's a dump of all the imports with "memmove" in the name from the various versions of `libstdc++-6.dll` that are installed by the Qt 5.0.2 with MinGW package:

```
C:\qt\5.0.2>for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir libstdc++-6.dll /s/b`) do dumpbin /imports %a | grep memmove

C:\qt\5.0.2>dumpbin /imports C:\qt\5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll | grep memmove
                  418 memmove

C:\qt\5.0.2>dumpbin /imports C:\qt\5.0.2\Tools\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll   | grep memmove
                  418 memmove

C:\qt\5.0.2>dumpbin /imports C:\qt\5.0.2\Tools\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libstdc++-6.dll   | grep memmove
                  418 memmove

C:\qt\5.0.2>dumpbin /imports C:\qt\5.0.2\Tools\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\lib64\libstdc++-6.dll   | grep memmove
                         402 memmove
```

No imports of `memmove_s` show up.

Your screenshots seem to show that `appmanager.exe` depends on `msvcrt.dll` directly as well. Perhaps that's where the dependency on `memmove_s` comes from? Try running the following command:

```
dumpbin /imports appmanager.exe | grep memmove
```

(you'll need a MS toolchain to get dumpbin, which is just a wrapper around `link /dump`. I couldn't get `objdump` to process `libstdc++-6.dll` usefully).

Comment: Thanks much! I'll do some poking around - I'm not using memmove_s explicitly anywhere, so I'll have to see what's up with that. Perhaps it's getting pulled in by a library

Comment: Ok, so my program is certainly invoking it, but I'm not explicitly calling `memmove_s` anywhere in my code. I'm assuming this means it is being used by a library I call (which I also built with MinGW). Scanning my library files with `dumpbin -all` shows that one of the libraries (Crypto++) contains a reference to `__imp__memmove_s`, so I assume it must be pulling it in, yes?

Comment: Follow up: Crypto++ did in fact use `memmove_s`, but provides its own implementation if it cannot find Microsoft's CRT additions. I disabled them in MinGW via `_mingw.h` and everything works great. Thanks again for your time and help!